# Removing table of content from my first slide

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I have used `‎\usetheme{PaloAlto}` for my presentation file in `beamer` class. How could I remove the table of content (titles of the sections and subsections)  from the left side of my first slide (Title slide)?

```
‎\documentclass{beamer}‎
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
‎\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}‎‎‎
‎\setbeamercovered{transparent}‎
‎‎\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,hyperref}‎ 
\makeatletter
\define@key{beamerframe}{t}[true]{% top
  \beamer@frametopskip=0pt %<-- was: .2cm plus .5\paperheight\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill\relax%
  \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=\beamer@frametopskip\relax%
  \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=\beamer@framebottomskip\relax%
  \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{%
    \def\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip{%
      \vskip-\partopsep\vskip-\topsep\vskip-\parskip%
      \global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}%
    \everypar{\global\let\beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip=\relax}}
}
‎
‎
\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}%{sidebar theme}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%
\makeatother

‎\title[ ]
‎{A Study on Estimability in Non-Regular Fractional Factorial Designs}‎

‎%\subtitle‎‎{it's really gorgeous}‎

‎\author[a,b] % (optional‎, ‎use only with lots of authors)‎
‎{Supervisor: \\[.1cm] Dr. H. Talayi\\[0.7cm] By: \\[0.1cm] Fahim B.\\[0.3cm]}‎

‎\institute[University of Isfahan]{
  ‎Department of Statistics\\‎[0.1cm]
  ‎University of Isfahan}‎
  ‎

‎\AtBeginSection[]‎
{
  ‎\begin{frame}<beamer>‎
    ‎\frametitle{Outline}‎
    ‎\tableofcontents[currentsection]%,currentsubsection]‎
  ‎\end{frame}‎
}


‎\begin{document}‎

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}
‎\begin{frame}‎
  ‎\frametitle{Outline}‎
  ‎\tableofcontents‎
  % ‎You might wish to add the option [pausesections]‎

‎\end{frame}‎

‎\section{Basic definitions}‎

‎\subsection{Definitions and examples}‎
‎\begin{frame}‎
    ‎\frametitle{Definition of a Minimal Surface}‎
‎bghvhvbhj bhjbhj hjj ikji 


‎\end{frame}‎


‎\section{Sketch of the gyroid family}‎

‎\begin{frame}\frametitle{Philosophy of the Problem}‎

‎\begin{block}{From $H \equiv 0$ to Complex Analysis} $G$ on $X$‎,  ‎and a holomorphic 1-form $dh$ on the $X$ so that‎:
‎\begin{itemize}‎
‎\item The  problem is solved‎
‎\item Certain mild compatibility conditions are satisfied‎
‎\end{itemize}‎
‎\end{block}‎
‎\pause‎
‎\begin{block}{From Complex Analysis to Euclidean Polygons}‎
‎The problem is typically \alert{hard}‎.  ‎
‎\end{frame}‎
  ‎\end{document}‎
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could redefine the sidebar template for this one frame or, as a quick hack, just change the font colour of sections and subsections on the title page to match the background. This way they won't be visible any more.

Please also note that you don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
%\usepackage{hyperref} 

\title[]{title}

\begin{document}

{
    \setbeamercolor{section in sidebar}{fg=structure.fg!20!white}
    \setbeamercolor{subsection in sidebar}{fg=structure.fg!20!white}
    \begin{frame}
        \maketitle
    \end{frame}
}

\section{Basic definitions}
\subsection{Definitions and examples}
\begin{frame}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]